# How do you get Discord mobile notifications to work while logged onto a computer without closing Discord on your PC?

Tags: discord

Whenever I'm logged into my computer, my Discord mobile notifications stop working--I only get PC notifications. Is there a fix without closing Discord on PC?

This happens both on my iOS and Android phone. Closing Discord on my PC immediately fixes this problem--when I do that, I get bombarded with old Discord notifications on my phone within the past hour or so.

I usually leave my computer on due it having scripts running, and I often forget to close Discord before exiting the room with my computer or exiting the house. My current solution is to use a remote desktop app to close Discord on my computer if I forget, but it often requires strong Internet to use, so it doesn't always work.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# MSGcorrupt
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

if [ "$1" != "--cron" ]; then
    
  4 
start.sh
@@ -24,7 +24,9 @@ JVM_ARGS="-server -Xms3G -Xmx3G"

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
ME=  basename $0 

cd  $ DIR


# SCRIPT:
# 
# Created by asim0v#5801 (discord)
#
#!/bin/bash 

IDENT=GPack
```

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).